# Which Frontend Framework for node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, reactjs, mean-stack

Recently I'm learning Node.js as a back end language. I found out that peoples are usually doing it with MEAN and my question is is it necessary to have a front end framework to work with Node.JS?

For the front end framework like angular and react, which one is more suitable for Nodejs?

I have did some research but i see most of the peoples using angular as A in MEAN for Nodejs. Can i know why?

Comment: Angular and react dont care about your back-end. They just want to use API to get and post data. So you can use any framework you like.

Comment: Its not necessary to use a front-end framework.

Comment: Angulary is really popular currently, but it's not mandatory to use a js framework at all. You can do basic HTML / JS for your front end

Comment: This question is far too broad to be answered here please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk thanks..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is absolutely **NOT** required to have a front end framework. You can use your nodejs only for API endpoints without any views actually getting rendered by your nodejs app. These end points can be used by some other front end app hosted somewhere else on some other technology. Moreover you can use nodejs app only for processing or a proxy or anything you want. (Although NodeJS is not recommended for CPU heavy operations like Analytics or so).

Angular has been in the market for over 6 years now and React has come in play only in 2013. So the developer community has been using Angular for longer time and hence it is more widely used. Its you which to use for front end.

AngularJS, ReactJS, Native JavaScript, JADE, Handlebars etc etc. You can use anything for frontend. Everyone has its own pros and cons.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a small addition: http://todomvc.com/ has small example apps in different FrontEnd Frameworks. Choose one you like.

Comment: Also Angular Lite, VueJS, Polymer, KnockoutJS, Ember and more =(

Comment: Thanks for your info... will try to kickstart with react first

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions in order:

No you don't need a front-end framework if you're not doing front-end. Look into frameworks suitable for back-end applications like ExpressJs or Hapi and some db like MongoDB or Redis etc.

At best you're going to use node to compile your react/angular part of the application in plain js-html-css understandable by browsers, removing all the fancy JSX/typescript/LESS stuff that makes your life less miserable as a developer.

MEAN, as in 'the MEAN stack', is a common bundle of technologies and it's name is the acronym of such technologies: MongoDB, ExpressJS, Angular, NodeJS. You can't have the MEAN stack without Angular for it's A or NodeJS for it's N.